# Find total sessions time looping through files in batch

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-line-interface

I've below commands in bat file which gives me 1st start time of syslog files and then 2nd command gives me end time of sessions.

**Commands:**

```
@FOR /F "tokens=12" %%a in ('findstr /c:"Syslog created by " 
H:\Newfolder\*test*.syslog') do SET OUTPUT=%%a
@FOR /F "tokens=7" %%a in ('findstr /c:"Session closed @@@" 
H:\Newfolder\*test*.syslog') do SET OUTPUT=%%a
```

**Output:**

```
H:\Newfolder>main.bat
H:\Newfolder>SET OUTPUT=10:30:30
H:\Newfolder>SET OUTPUT=20:50:25
H:\Newfolder>SET OUTPUT=20:50:45
H:\Newfolder>SET OUTPUT=20:55:25
```

At the end I'm interested in total time of sessions.

e.g. **Total syslog run time is: 12:24:55**

I'm aware about [this code](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-tdiff.html) but don't know how to make use of it.

**Sample log file:**

```
Syslog created by shuklak sklkkk wedwd on Thursday, 9 August 2018, 20:47:25 on India Standard Time
...Some stuff here..
Session closed @@@ 9 August 2018, 20:50:45 on India Standard Time
```

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service.

Comment: How does that add up to 12 hours, 24 minutes and 55 seconds? To use the `TDIFF` batch file you would use the `CALL` command from your existing batch file. It shows you right in the help  how to use it. `tdiff.cmd StartTime StopTime`.  So you would use: `CALL tdiff.cmd 10:30:30 20:50:25`

Comment: @Squashman 1st syslog time = 1st end of seesion  (20:50:45) - 1st start of seesion (10:30:30). Similary for 2nd syslog, then I sumed it . 1st 2 output values are for start of sessions while other 2 are end of sessions.

Comment: @Experimenter, that is not what your output examples show.

Comment: @Squashman, 1st command is giving start times and then 2nd gives end time of sessions. Yeah, code in the link I mentioned may not be useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing original log lines, I can only depend on your code.

- IMO you should filter with a RegEx both line types to have them in chronological order.
- the link you provided shows how to calculate time differences in one day.
- the 1st for parsing findstring output selects the lines,
- the echo findstr differentiates start from stop time
- the subroutine `:TimeToSecs` splits HH:mm:ss into parts and calculates seconds in day, stores start,stop times,seconds and also calculates difference and total.

**EDIT incorporated a Secs2HMS sub routine**

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\08\09\SO_51773307.cmd
@Echo off
PushD "H:\Newfolder\" ||(Echo couldn't find dir & Pause & Exit /B 1)

Set "TotalSecs=0"
For %%F in ("*test*.syslog") Do For /F "delims=" %%A in ('
    findstr /I "Syslog.created.by Session.closed.@@@" "%%F"
') Do (
    Set "Flag="
    Echo=%%A|findstr /I "Syslog.created.by" 2>&1>Nul && Set "Flag=Start"
    if defined Flag (
        FOR /F "tokens=11" %%T in ("%%A") Do Call :TimeToSecs Start "%%T"
    ) Else (
        FOR /F "tokens=7" %%T in ("%%A") Do Call :TimeToSecs Stop "%%T"
    )
)
Echo:
PopD
Goto :Eof

:TimeToSecs
Set "%1_HMS=%~2"
Echo:%~2|Findstr "[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" 2>&1>Nul || (Echo wrong format %2&Goto :Eof)
For /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%H in ("%~2"
) Do Set /A "%1=(1%%H-100)*60*60+(1%%I-100)*60+(1%%J-100)"
If %1 neq Stop Goto :Eof
Set /A "Diff=Stop-Start,TotalSecs+=Diff"
Call :Secs2HMS Dur %Diff%
Call :Secs2HMS TotalDur %TotalSecs%
Echo Session from %Start_HMS% to %Stop_HMS% Duration %Dur% TotalDuration %TotalDur%
Goto :Eof

:Secs2HMS var value
setlocal
set /a "HH=%2/3600,mm=(%2-HH*3600)/60+100,ss=%2 %% 60+100"
Set "HHmmss=    %HH%:%mm:~-2%:%ss:~-2%"
endlocal&set "%1=%HHmmss:~-10%
Goto :Eof
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\08\09\SO_51773307.cmd
Session from 08:47:25 to 20:50:45 Duration   12:03:20 TotalDuration   12:03:20
Session from 10:30:30 to 20:50:25 Duration   10:19:55 TotalDuration   22:23:15
Session from 20:50:45 to 20:55:25 Duration    0:04:40 TotalDuration   22:27:55
Session from 10:30:30 to 20:50:25 Duration   10:19:55 TotalDuration   32:47:50
Session from 20:50:45 to 20:55:25 Duration    0:04:40 TotalDuration   32:52:30
```

Comment: Please find sample log file text in question.

Comment: I did struggle with the batch because 1st when using a wildcard findstr includes the filename in the output and 2nd you didn't count right, in `Syslog created by shuklak sklkkk wedwd on Thursday, 9 August 2018, 20:47:25` it is the 11th token, not the 12th. See changed batch with an additional validity check for a time.

Comment: Great! How can I get total time in HMS format like I shown in example. Also how can I get last 2 columns neatly (maybe right) aligned.

Comment: The usual way to acknowledge a helpful answer is to vote up and/or accept the answer. I'll edit the answer, in general use set /a to divide Totalsecs by 3600 and 60 and use sub string to align

Comment: Wonderful! Acrually I had tried for alignment and converting to HMS but no success. Thank you working as expected...